# SQL Select query to return Foreign Key value and update original value

Tags: sql-server

I am somewhat new to MS SQL but I have been able to figure out how to get a Foreign key to return through a query, but I cannot figure out how to make it update the original value.

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT prd_pk, prd_alt_desc
FROM RM_AM.dbo.product
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT prd_pk FROM dbo.Bn_Import WHERE prd_alt_desc = dbo.Bn_Import.Commodity);
```

I think I need a variable to do it, but I don't know enough of how to structure the query.

```
+------------+------------------+-------------------------+------------------+-----------------+-------------+
| Ship Date  |   Original ETA   | Confirmed Delivery Date |   Current ETA    |    Commodity    | Load Status |
+------------+------------------+-------------------------+------------------+-----------------+-------------+
| 10/9/2018  | 10/16/2018 11:48 | 10/19/2018              |                  | SANDFRAC4070MES | L           |
| 10/1/2018  | 10/1/2018 18:49  | 10/4/2018               | 10/18/2018 10:28 | SANDFRAC4070MES | L           |
| 10/11/2018 | 10/18/2018 11:48 | 10/20/2018              |                  | SANDFRAC4070MES | L           |
| 10/9/2018  | 10/16/2018 11:48 | 10/19/2018              |                  | SANDFRAC4070MES | L           |
| 10/1/2018  | 10/1/2018 18:49  | 10/4/2018               | 10/18/2018 10:28 | SANDFRAC4070MES | L           |
| 10/10/2018 | 10/17/2018 11:48 | 10/20/2018              |                  | SANDFRAC4070MES | L           |
| 10/16/2018 | 10/19/2018 6:00  | 10/21/2018              | 10/19/2018 1:04  |                 | L           |
| 10/9/2018  | 10/16/2018 11:48 | 10/19/2018              |                  | SANDFRAC4070MES | L           |
| 10/4/2018  | 10/11/2018 11:48 | 10/13/2018              |                  | SANDFRAC4070MES | L           |
| 10/16/2018 | 10/19/2018 6:00  | 10/21/2018              | 10/19/2018 1:04  |                 | L           |
| 9/17/2018  | 9/17/2018 18:49  | 9/21/2018               |                  | SANDFRAC4070MES | L           |
| 10/1/2018  | 10/1/2018 18:49  | 10/4/2018               | 10/18/2018 10:28 | SANDFRAC4070MES | L           |
| 10/9/2018  | 10/16/2018 11:48 | 10/18/2018              |                  | SANDFRAC4070MES | L           |
| 10/9/2018  | 10/16/2018 11:48 | 10/19/2018              |                  | SANDFRAC4070MES | L           |
| 10/15/2018 | 10/18/2018 6:00  | 10/21/2018              | 10/19/2018 4:24  |                 | L           |
| 10/4/2018  | 10/11/2018 11:48 | 10/13/2018              |                  |                 | L           |
| 10/1/2018  | 10/1/2018 18:49  | 10/4/2018               | 10/18/2018 10:28 | SANDFRAC4070MES | L           |
| 10/16/2018 | 10/19/2018 6:00  | 10/21/2018              | 10/19/2018 1:04  |                 | L           |
| 10/6/2018  | 10/13/2018 11:48 | 10/16/2018              |                  | SANDFRAC4070MES | L           |
| 10/11/2018 | 10/18/2018 11:48 | 10/20/2018              | 10/19/2018 0:02  | SANDFRAC4070MES | L           |
| 10/9/2018  | 10/16/2018 11:48 | 10/19/2018              |                  | SANDFRAC4070MES | L           |
| 10/4/2018  | 10/11/2018 11:48 | 10/14/2018              |                  | SANDFRAC4070MES | L           |
| 10/1/2018  | 10/1/2018 18:49  | 10/4/2018               | 10/18/2018 10:28 | SANDFRAC4070MES | L           |
| 10/9/2018  | 10/16/2018 11:48 | 10/19/2018              |                  | SANDFRAC4070MES | L           |
| 10/9/2018  | 10/16/2018 11:48 | 10/19/2018              |                  | SANDFRAC4070MES | L           |
| 10/4/2018  | 10/11/2018 11:48 | 10/14/2018              |                  | SANDFRAC4070MES | L           |
| 10/9/2018  | 10/16/2018 11:48 | 10/18/2018              |                  | SANDFRAC4070MES | L           |
| 9/14/2018  | 9/22/2018 19:50  | 9/26/2018               | 10/18/2018 14:01 | SANDFRAC4070MES | L           |
| 10/4/2018  | 10/11/2018 11:48 | 10/13/2018              |                  | SANDFRAC4070MES | L           |
| 10/7/2018  | 10/14/2018 11:48 | 10/18/2018              |                  |                 | L           |
| 10/9/2018  | 10/16/2018 11:48 | 10/19/2018              |                  | SANDFRAC4070MES | L           |
| 10/1/2018  | 10/1/2018 18:49  | 10/4/2018               | 10/18/2018 10:28 | SANDFRAC4070MES | L           |
| 9/17/2018  | 9/17/2018 18:49  | 9/21/2018               |                  | SANDFRAC4070MES | L           |
+------------+------------------+-------------------------+------------------+-----------------+-------------+
```

I need to change the commodity from SANDFRAC4070MES to 6710

6710 is the Foreign Key for another table in our database.

Comment: you could use output. create a temp table first                                                      
    create table #temp (Id int)  SELECT prd_pk,prd_alt_desc output inserted.id into #temp(Id) FROM RM_AM.dbo.product where EXISTS (SELECT prd_pk FROM dbo.Bn_Import WHERE prd_alt_desc = dbo.Bn_Import.Commodity);    select * from #temp

Comment: When I do that I get:Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near 'inserted'.

Comment: Can you post the sample data and expected output, for more clarity?

Comment: I updated it above

Comment: Your question needs clarification. The sample data and its relation to the query you supplied doesn't make sense. Explain your table structures and what you really to do.

Comment: @MikeBrown specificially this is how you can output to do something later:create table #product (prd_pk int, prd_alt_desc varchar(max))

insert into #product 
inserted output.* into #product(prd_pk,prd_alt_desc)
(prd_pk,prd_alt_desc)
SELECT prd_pk, prd_alt_desc

FROM RM_AM.dbo.product
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT prd_pk FROM dbo.Bn_Import WHERE prd_alt_desc = dbo.Bn_Import.Commodity);

Comment: @SRahmani I keep getting an error when using your code at the point of inserted

Comment: @CetinBasoz  The data above is a import of data into a temp table. In the actual table the Commodity is listed as the primary key and has to be listed that way for me to merge the data into the working table for our applicaiton. I am trying to pull the key from the other database and place it in my temp table.

Comment: @MikeBrown sorry for the bad syntax - this should work: 
create table #product (prd_pk int, prd_alt_desc varchar(max))

insert into #product 
output inserted.prd_pk,inserted.prd_alt_desc into #product(prd_pk,prd_alt_desc)
(prd_pk,prd_alt_desc)
SELECT prd_pk, prd_alt_desc
FROM RM_AM.dbo.product
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT prd_pk FROM dbo.Bn_Import WHERE prd_alt_desc = dbo.Bn_Import.Commodity);

select * from #product

Comment: @SRahmani, Will that replace the values that are there or just add additional lines to the table?

Comment: @MikeBrown it will save your values you output to that temp table - you temporarily have them preserved and can use that for whatever other manipulation you need to write.

Comment: @SRahmani That helps, I just need to also figure out how to make it overwrite the existing value based on what is there in the original table. Any thoughts?

Comment: @MikeBrown yep. If you can use that temp table primary key - which should match your production table you can update the column based on that. if you understand that and can attempt to write it I am happy to review it.

Comment: @MikeBrown example : update a set column = u.value from table a inner join #products u on a.prd_pk = u.prd_pk. If you can write something similar that would be ideal.

Comment: I don't see a change in your question. It is still unclear and structures are missing.

Comment: @SRahmani This is what I have come up with so far.

 create table #prdts (prd_pk int, prd_alt_desc varchar(max)) 

insert into #prdts output inserted.prd_pk,inserted.prd_alt_desc into #prdts(prd_pk,prd_alt_desc)  SELECT prd_pk, prd_alt_desc FROM RM_AM.dbo.product 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT prd_pk FROM dbo.Bn_Import WHERE prd_alt_desc = dbo.Bn_Import.Commodity); select * from #prdts 
update Bn_Import
set Bn_Import.commodity = u.value from dbo.Bn_Import inner join #prdts u on a.prd_pk = u.prd_pk

I am however getting and invalid object error

Comment: @MikeBrown sorry for the delay - I just saw this. try:                                   create table #prdts (prd_pk int, prd_alt_desc varchar(max))
  insert into #prdts (prd_pk,prd_alt_desc)

  output inserted.prd_pk,inserted.prd_alt_desc into #prdts(prd_pk,prd_alt_desc) 
  SELECT prd_pk, prd_alt_desc 
  FROM RM_AM.dbo.product 
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT prd_pk FROM dbo.Bn_Import WHERE prd_alt_desc = dbo.Bn_Import.Commodity); select * from #prdts update Bn_Import set Bn_Import.commodity = u.value from dbo.Bn_Import inner join #prdts u on a.prd_pk = u.prd_pk